# VBA for Access- Compare function reporting "false" or #error everytime

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

I am developing an Access DB for a little project at work. We have an ODBC Database that has a list of certain servers entered into a web client. I tried writing a VBA function to take them, convert them to lowercase, and assign the string to "true" if they match, and "false" if not. I use the function in a query so you can search for ranges of server and so-on and so-forth.

```
Public Function InWhatsUp(field1 As Field, field2 As Field) As String
  If (LCase(field1.Value) = LCase(field2.Value)) Then
    InWhatsUp = "True"
  Else
    InWhatsUp = "False"
  End If
 Return
End Function
```

I haven't been able to find much relevant research besides using an IIF to compare, but the results all turn up as "false" there as well. Thank you in advance

Comment: If one or both of your fields is `Null`, you won't get meaningful results. `LCase(Null)` is `Null` and `Null = Null` returns `Null`, not a Boolean, so your `If` block will always return `"False"`

Answer (score 1):

A query can never pass objects like `Field` to a VBA function.

Use parameter data type `String`, or if the values can be NULL, `Variant`.

Since normal string comparison is <s>always</s> usually (see below) case-insensitive, you can then simply do

```
InWhatsUp = (str1 = str2)
```

or directly in the query:

```
Identical: IIf(server1 = server2, "True", "False")
```

If you need case-sensitive string comparison, you must use

```
StrComp(string1, string2, vbBinaryCompare)
```

**Edit**

> normal string comparison is always case-insensitive

That's only true if you keep the `Option Compare Database` that is by default inserted in Access VBA modules.

If you change it to `Option Compare Binary` or remove it altogether, string comparisons are case-sensitive.

Thanks @ThunderFrame for the correction.

Comment: Actually it depends on the `Option Compare` setting of the module. See Edit. @ThunderFrame

Comment: Actually, in the Immediate Window, it depends on the database setting for string comparisons. Better to be explicit by using `StrComp`, and then it's reliable across VBA hosts.

Comment: I see, thanks. I just tried unsuccessfully to **find** this database setting. `? CurrentDb.CollatingOrder` gives `1033`, which [translates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193485.aspx) to **dbSortGeneral** (English, German, French, and Portuguese collating order), which is case-insensitive. But where in the database options window do I set this? Do you know? @ThunderFrame

Comment: You tested `Null` values (with `Variant` args)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function InWhatsUp(field1 As Variant, field2 As Variant) As Boolean

    If IsNull(field1) Or IsNull(field2) Then Exit Function
    If (Len(field1) = False) Or (Len(field2) = False) Then Exit Function
    If IsError(field1) Or IsError(field2) Then Exit Function

    InWhatsUp = StrComp(field1, field2, vbTextCompare)

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print InWhatsUp("aaB", "aAb")
    Debug.Print InWhatsUp("aaB", "abb")
    Debug.Print InWhatsUp(Null, "")
End Sub
```

- You do not have `return` in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). Instead you refer to the function.
- It is a good idea to make the function `Boolean`, if the only two values to return are `True` and `False`.
- As far as you are working in Access, probably there could be one exception - if the two strings are `""`, probably you would like to see `False`, depending on your business logic. The `IsError()`  is due to the same logic.
- Checking whether the input is `Null` is something that is quite handy in Access. And following the logic of plenty of languages, a `Null` is never the same as another `Null`.

Comment: Thank you for the input! The field still displays #Error when the query is run. My inputs are the fields from the table, should it be .value (or something) of the field?

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `StrComp` function that is designed for this type of comparison, rather than reinventing the wheel, and somewhat inefficiently too. I suspect there are also some bugs in your function with certain unicode characters.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - `StrComp` is quite handy indeed.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - yeah, `Null` error is important, too much working in Excel made me forget obvious things.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make that function return a `Boolean`. Its job is to determine a *Boolean* result - whoever calls it can then decide to turn that Boolean into a `String`, but most callers would normally run Boolean logic with it, and if that's the case then returning a `String` requires VBA to perform implicit type conversions all over the place.

And since it's a string utility function, it doesn't even need to know about a `Field` - give it two `Variant` values so it can take a `Null`, and pass them by value:

```
Public Function AreTheSame(ByVal string1 As Variant, ByVal string2 As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsNull(string1) Or IsNull(string2) Then Exit Function
    AreTheSame = (StrComp(string1, string2, vbTextCompare) = 0)
End Function
```

Now you can test this function anywhere, with any input:

```
?AreTheSame(Null, "ABC")  -> False
?AreTheSame(Null, Null)   -> False
?AreTheSame("abc", "ABC") -> True
```

If you want to treat to `Null` values as equal, then you need to coalesce them into empty strings - and since null-coalescing is a concern of its own, I'd make another, separate function for that:

```
Public Function Coalesce(ByVal value As Variant) As String
    If IsNull(value) Then
        Coalesce = vbNullString
    Else
        Coalesce = CStr(value)
    End If
End Function

Public Function AreTheSame(ByVal string1 As Variant, ByVal string2 As Variant) As Boolean
    AreTheSame = (StrComp(Coalesce(string1), Coalesce(string2), vbTextCompare) = 0)
End Function
```

With that, two `null` values are treated as empty strings. I'd probably use an optional parameter to make that behavior configurable from the call site - ditto for case-sensitivity.

Comment: `AreTheSame(Null,vbNullString)` returns true too (with Coalesce). Check needed.

Comment: Maybe `AreTheSame = (StrComp(Coalesce(string1), Coalesce(string2), vbTextCompare) = 0) Xor (IsNull(string1) Xor IsNull(string2))` ?

Comment: Argh, that fails for `AreTheSame("aaB", Null)`. Adding `If IsNull(string1) Xor IsNull(string2) Then Exit Function` should work and is easier to read. Can we expect a significant performance increase by first comparing String-Length before compare the strings (or not if if not equal)?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher yup. That's why pulling it into its own function is awesome: you fix that bug *once* ;-)